# Management Studio disconnects from a server when opening a table

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Everytime I open some table or procedure in Management Studio, it disconnect me for a while. It's roughly about 5 sec., but it's quite annoying each time I want to view some data.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by open a table or a procedure? It is unclear what you are doing when this happens.

Comment: Table: right-click>Select TOP 1000
Procedure: right-click>Modify

Comment: To be honest you shouldn't be using that to edit data. You should be using an update statement. But not sure why the issue you are mentioning is happening. How do you know it is disconnecting?

Comment: 1) I don't to edit data. I want to see them.
2) Because it writes "Disconnect" and it retrives no data for a while

Comment: Why not simply write a select statement to view data?

Comment: ...because it disconnects me for a while. It does not matter whether I click SELECT TOP 1000 or write the query manualy.

Comment: That is strange. never heard of that happening.

Comment: Yeah...me too. [Another 15 characters]